# Ghostscript error with a surface in pst-solides-3d

Tags: errors, pstricks, ghostscript

I'm discovering the extremely cool [pst-solides-3d](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-solides3d) package.

The code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}


\begin{document}

    \begin{pspicture}(0,0)(3,5)

    \psset{viewpoint=60 80 30 rtp2xyz,Decran=60,lightsrc=viewpoint}

    \defFunction{g}(u,v){sin(u)*sin(t)}{u}{sin(u)*cos(t)}

    \psSolid[object=surfaceparametree,linewidth=0.5\pslinewidth, base=0 pi 0 pi,fillcolor=yellow!50,incolor=green!50, function=g, ngrid=60 0.4]%

    \end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

should generate a drawing of the surface g(u,v), but instead when I compile, I get an error from ghoscript:

```
$latex test.tex
[...]
Output written on test.dvi (1 page, 5284 bytes).
Transcript written on test.log.
$dvips test.dvi
[...]
$ps2pdf test.ps
Error: /typecheck in --sin--
Operand stack:
   S   --nostringval--   --nostringval--
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1910   1   3   %oparray_pop   1909   1   3   %oparray_pop   1893   1   3   %oparray_pop   1787   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   1   1   60   --nostringval--   %for_pos_int_continue   1   1   7   --nostringval--   %for_pos_int_continue   --nostringval--   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1158/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:87/200(L)--   --dict:739/1012(L)--   --dict:175/300(L)--   --dict:38/200(L)--   --dict:184/200(L)--   --dict:739/1012(L)--   --dict:14/20(L)--   --dict:2/3(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: 2
Current file position is 359102
GPL Ghostscript RELEASE CANDIDATE 9.00: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

I can't open the ps file either, and the dvi file is empty.

Where does that terrible error come from ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems in your code:

1. Your function can either be supplied in algebraic notation or using [Reverse Polish Notation (RPN)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation). The latter (RPN) is the default. If you want the former, you need to specify it using `\defFunction[algebraic]{..}...`. You have supplied it in algebraic notation without that option.
2. Your function is using parameters `u` and `v` to determine each of the coordinates of `g`. Put differently, (x,y,z) of `g` is specified in terms of `u` and `v`. However, both x(u,v) and z(u,v) in your definition has been defined in terms of `u` and `t` instead.

Taking these two points into consideration, you need

```
\defFunction[algebraic]{g}(u,v){sin(u)*sin(v)}{u}{sin(u)*cos(v)}
```

[image: pst-solides3d to plot a 3D surface]