# Making mesh grid lines transparent in surface plot with pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, 3d

I need to make a partly transparent, one color, surface plot. Additionally I want to control the transparency of mesh lines. Running this code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[]
\addplot3[surf, color=blue, opacity=0.5, domain=-2:2, faceted color=blue] {exp(-x^2-y^2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Produces the desired result only for the faces. Does pgfplots provide an option to control the transparency of mesh lines too?

[image: Transparent surface with mesh lines visible]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `opacity` parameter controls transparency of mesh lines and surfaces. To make mesh lines much more transparent you can add `fill opacity` and decrease `opacity`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[]
\addplot3[surf, color=blue, opacity=0.01,fill opacity=0.5, domain=-2:2, faceted color=blue] {exp(-x^2-y^2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

the same with `pst-solides3d`. Run it with `xelatex`:

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\begin{document}

\psset{viewpoint=50 20 20 rtp2xyz,Decran=50,lightsrc=viewpoint}
\begin{pspicture}(-3.5,-2)(3.5,3)
\psSurface[opacity=0.7,strokeopacity=0.4,fillcolor=blue!80,linecolor=blue!40,
           linewidth=0.2pt,algebraic,ngrid=0.1 0.1,axesboxed,
           Zmin=0,Zmax=2,showAxes=false](-2,-2)(2,2){2*e^(-x^2-y^2)}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]