# Switch colormap and interior colormap

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, diagrams

Why is it problamatic to switch the colormap and the interior colormap?  The following works fine:

```
    mesh/interior colormap name=hot,
    colormap/blackwhite,
```

but this does not:

```
    mesh/interior colormap name=blackwhite,
    colormap/hot,
```

I want the second figure to have the interior in gray scale.  I realize that this probably can be done by changing the domain and/or function, but would prefer to be able to just switch the colormaps as that would be much simpler.

[image]

### References:

- Figure is adapted from [Cut-off cone in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29491/4301)

### Code:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}%

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    hide axis,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    %% ------------------------------------ This is fine
    mesh/interior colormap name=hot,
    colormap/blackwhite, 
 ]
  \addplot3 [domain=-1.5:1.5,surf, shader=faceted] {-exp(-x^2-y^2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    hide axis,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    %% ------------------------------------ This does not work
%    mesh/interior colormap name=blackwhite,
    colormap/hot, 
 ]
  \addplot3 [domain=-1.5:1.5,surf, shader=faceted] {-exp(-x^2-y^2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Related Question: [Defining custom colormap](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/359526/4301).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The design at this point is a little bit confusing. The situation is somehow like

```
\def\employBlackWhite{
    \def\colormap@BlackWhite{
        black --> white
    }
}
\show\colormap@BlackWhite
```

and the result is of course undefined.

so you have to say `\pgfplotsset{colormap/blackwhite}` in order to put the definition of `blackwhite` into the memory. Or, more compactly

```
\begin{axis}[
  hide axis,
  xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
  colormap/black, % employ blackwhite
  colormap/hot,   % employ hot & change the default to hot
  mesh/interior colormap name=blackwhite, % change the interior color
]
```

---

According to the manual

> `/pgfplots/colormap name={⟨color map name⟩}`
>   Changes the current color map to the already defined map named `⟨color map name⟩`.
>
> `/pgfplots/colormap={⟨name⟩}{⟨color specification⟩}`
>   Defines a new colormap named `⟨name⟩` according to `⟨color specification⟩` and activates it using `colormap name={⟨name⟩}`.

So the same logic applies to the pair

> `/pgfplots/mesh/interior colormap name={⟨map name⟩}`
>   `/pgfplots/mesh/interior colormap={⟨map name⟩}{⟨colormap specification⟩}`

They are pretty much like the relation between

> `\usebeamertemplate`
>   `\setbeamertemplate`

Comment: +1 Of course. My reaction with the potential bug was too hasty. I'll delete it together with my answer.