# Defining custom colormap

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, diagrams, 3d

Using a custom color map as such works fine:

```
\begin{axis}[
    mesh/interior colormap name=hot,
    colormap={slategraywhite}{rgb255=(112,128,144) rgb255=(255,159,101)},
 ]
```

and the first MWE below yields:

[image]

However, this requires that if I need this in another plot than I have to copy over the color specifications. Thus, would prefer to define a custom colormap with a name

```
\pgfplotsset{%
    colormap={slategraywhite}{rgb255=(112,128,144) rgb255=(255,159,101)}%
}%
```

and reuse it.  However, I am unable to get the second MWE which uses a named colormap to work.

### References:

- This is probably related [Switch colormap and interior colormap](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/359407/4301), but have been unable to adapt the solution provided there for this case.

---

### Code: `Manually Specified Colormap`

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}%

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    hide axis,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    mesh/interior colormap name=hot,
    colormap={slategraywhite}{rgb255=(112,128,144) rgb255=(255,159,101)},% <--- This works fine.
 ]
  \addplot3 [domain=-1.5:1.5,surf, shader=faceted] {-exp(-x^2-y^2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

---

### Code: `Named Colormap`

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}%

\pgfplotsset{%
    colormap={slategraywhite}{rgb255=(112,128,144) rgb255=(255,159,101)}%
}%    
\pgfplotsset{colormap/slategraywhite}% <-- activate colormap
\pgfplotsset{colormap/blackwhite}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    hide axis,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    mesh/interior colormap name=hot,
    colormap/slategraywhite,%         <--- How do I get this working.
 ]
  \addplot3 [domain=-1.5:1.5,surf, shader=faceted] {-exp(-x^2-y^2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Peter, does one of the two answers solve your problem or do you need further assistance? In the first case, would you mind accepting one of the answers?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `colormap/<colormap name>` stuff are predefined styles, i.e. they (i) either define the colormap itself which activates them too, or (ii) they activate them by calling them their name

```
\pgfplotsset{
    % (i) define the colormap and activate it
    colormap={<colormap name>}{ ... },
    % (ii) call an already defined colormap to activate it
    colormap/<colormap name>/.style={
        colormap name=<colormap name>,
    },
}
```

which of course you didn't do for your custom colormap. So see the comments in the following code on how you just activate it to use it either globally or locally.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.14
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}
\pgfplotsset{
    % this *defines* a custom colormap ...
    colormap={slategraywhite}{
        rgb255=(112,128,144)
        rgb255=(255,159,101)
    },
%    % ... but this command does not *activate* a custom colormap ...
%    colormap/slategraywhite,        % <-- activate colormap
%    % this could either be done here (globally), which makes it the default
%    % used colormap, by specifying ...
%    colormap name=slategraywhite,
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        hide axis,
        mesh/interior colormap name=hot,
        % ... or you activate it here (locally)
        colormap name=slategraywhite,
    ]
        \addplot3 [domain=-1.5:1.5,surf, shader=faceted] {-exp(-x^2-y^2)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Using this way of defining and globally or locally activating a colormap in combination with `pgfplotstable` did not work as expected. The function `\pgfplotscreatecolormap{test}{...}` as mentioned [below](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/359532) only with `/pgfplots/colormap name=test` *does work* though.

Answer (score 6):

Let us see how the package author does the job:

In `pgfplots.code.tex` line 36 it input `pgfplotscolormap.code.tex`. In the later file line 2372

> ```
> \pgfplotscreatecolormap{hot}{color(0cm)=(blue); color(1cm)=(yellow); color(2cm)=(orange); color(3cm)=(red)}
> ```

In `pgfplots.code.tex` line 4019-47

> ```
> /pgfplots/colormap/hot/.style={
>   % attention: copied from pgfplots.colormap.code.tex:
>   /pgfplots/colormap={hot}{color(0cm)=(blue); color(1cm)=(yellow); color(2cm)=(orange); color(3cm)=(red)}
> },
> /pgfplots/colormap/viridis/.style={%
>   /pgfplots/colormap={viridis}{%
>       rgb=(0.267,0.00487,0.32942)
>       rgb=(0.28192,0.08966,0.41241)
>       rgb=(0.28026,0.1657,0.4765)
>       rgb=(0.26366,0.23763,0.51877)
>       rgb=(0.23744,0.3052,0.54192)
>       rgb=(0.20862,0.36775,0.55267)
>       rgb=(0.18225,0.42618,0.55711)
>       rgb=(0.1592,0.48224,0.55807)
>       rgb=(0.13777,0.53749,0.5549)
>       rgb=(0.12115,0.59274,0.54465)
>       rgb=(0.12808,0.64775,0.5235)
>       rgb=(0.18065,0.7014,0.48819)
>       rgb=(0.27415,0.75198,0.4366)
>       rgb=(0.39517,0.79747,0.36775)
>       rgb=(0.53561,0.83578,0.2819)
>       rgb=(0.68895,0.86545,0.18272)
>       rgb=(0.84557,0.88733,0.0997)
>       rgb=(0.99324,0.90616,0.14394)
>   }%
> },
> % instantiate viridis such that it is in memory by default:
> /pgfplots/colormap/viridis,
> % ... but reuse hot since it is used to be the default since the
> % beginning:
> /pgfplots/colormap name=hot,
> %
> /pgfplots/colormap/hot2/.style={
>   /pgfplots/colormap={hot2}{[1cm]rgb255(0cm)=(0,0,0) rgb255(3cm)=(255,0,0) rgb255(6cm)=(255,255,0)
>   rgb255(8cm)=(255,255,255)}
> },
> /pgfplots/colormap/bluered/.style={
>   /pgfplots/colormap={bluered}{rgb255(0cm)=(0,0,180); rgb255(1cm)=(0,255,255); rgb255(2cm)=(100,255,0);
>   rgb255(3cm)=(255,255,0); rgb255(4cm)=(255,0,0); rgb255(5cm)=(128,0,0)}
> },
> /pgfplots/colormap/cool/.style={
>   /pgfplots/colormap={cool}{rgb255(0cm)=(255,255,255); rgb255(1cm)=(0,128,255); rgb255(2cm)=(255,0,255)}
> },
> /pgfplots/colormap/greenyellow/.style={
>   /pgfplots/colormap={greenyellow}{rgb255(0cm)=(0,128,0); rgb255(1cm)=(255,255,0)}
> },
> /pgfplots/colormap/redyellow/.style={
>   /pgfplots/colormap={redyellow}{rgb255(0cm)=(255,0,0); rgb255(1cm)=(255,255,0)}
> },
> /pgfplots/colormap/blackwhite/.style={
>   /pgfplots/colormap={blackwhite}{gray(0cm)=(0); gray(1cm)=(1)}
> },
> /pgfplots/colormap/violet/.style={
>   /pgfplots/colormap={violet}{rgb255=(25,25,122) color=(white) rgb255=(238,140,238)}
> },
> /pgfplots/colormap/jet/.style={
>   /pgfplots/colormap={jet}{rgb255(0cm)=(0,0,128) rgb255(1cm)=(0,0,255) rgb255(3cm)=(0,255,255) rgb255(5cm)=(255,255,0)
>   rgb255(7cm)=(255,0,0) rgb255(8cm)=(128,0,0)}
> },
> ```

In English, the package does the following

- activate `hot`, use `hot`. (only this is in `pgfplotscolormap.code.tex`)
- define `hot`
- define `viridis`
- activate `viridis`, use `viridis` instead of `hot`
- use `hot` instead of `viridis`
- define `hot2`
- define `bluered`
- define `cool`
- define `greenyellow`
- define `redyellow`
- define `blackwhite`
- define `violet`
- define `jet`

Therefore the status is

- `hot` is defined, activated, and using. (Green light )
- `viridis` is defined and activated. (Yellow light )
- `hot2`, ..., `jet` are defined. (Red light )

---

We conclude that there are five ways to use a colormap:

- use `hot` by doing nothing ()
- use `viridis` by either `colormap name=viridis` or `colormap/viridis`. ()
- use `hot2`, ..., `jet` by `colormap/jet`. ()

  - from the second time on, one can use `colormap name=jet`.
- define a custom colormap by `colormap/foo/.style={colormap={foo}{...}}`.

  - And then activate and use it by `colormap/foo`.
  - from the second time on, one can use `colormap name=foo`. (beware of grouping)
- activate a custom colormap by `colormap={bar}{...}`.

  - from the second time on, one can use `colormap name=bar`. (beware of grouping)

Comment: Please correct your typo: `ciridis` should be `viridis`.

Comment: @StefanPinnow Thanks. That is embarrassing :P

Comment: I would say: Shit happens ;)