# pgfkeys error with pgfplots/colormap

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfkeys

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{%
  compat=newest,
  colormap={orangeyellow}{color=(orange) color=(yellow)}
}

\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
         domain=0:180,
         y domain=0:360,
         z buffer=sort,
         colormap/orangeyellow]
         \addplot3[surf] ({sin(x)*cos(y)},{sin(x)*sin(y)},{cos(x)});
      \end{axis}      
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I get the error

```
Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/colormap/orangeyellow' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
```

However, the output is rendered correctly, because (as I suppose) pgfplots automatically uses the last colormap that was defined. This kind of solves the problem for now, but if I were to define to colormaps, I would still need a real solution.

Also (and mainly), I do not understand why pgfkeys thinks I am referring to `/tikz/colormap` instead of `/pgfplots/colormap`. It clearly does not do this for the predefined `colormap/redyellow`, nor for any other of the keys I pass to the `axis` environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct key to use is `colormap name=orangeyellow`. See e.g. [this related answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/359528/121799) for more options.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}%
\pgfplotsset{%
  compat=newest,
  colormap={orangeyellow}{
  color=(orange) color=(yellow)
  },
}

\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
         domain=0:180,
         y domain=0:360,
         z buffer=sort,
         colormap name=orangeyellow]
         \addplot3[surf] ({sin(x)*cos(y)},{sin(x)*sin(y)},{cos(x)});
      \end{axis}      
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to use your syntax, you need to define a style of that name.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}%
\pgfplotsset{%
  compat=newest,
  colormap={orangeyellow}{
  color=(orange) color=(yellow)
  },
  colormap/orangeyellow/.style={
        colormap name=orangeyellow,
    },
}

\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
         domain=0:180,
         y domain=0:360,
         z buffer=sort,
         colormap/orangeyellow]
         \addplot3[surf] ({sin(x)*cos(y)},{sin(x)*sin(y)},{cos(x)});
      \end{axis}      
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for that answer and also for the link to the related question which I unfortunately did not find before asking mine...

Comment: @PhilippImhof You're welcome!