# Presumed error of pgfplots in the "cutting" of a surface

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, 3d

I'm struggling with a 3D representation through the use of the package `pgfplots`. I'm faced with an alleged error in `pgfplots` (from my point of view). Consider the txt file (which is attached [here](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=DBCFFFE4C9028336!2822&authkey=!ANz-gcTBtB93rZ4)) and the following code that uses it:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{/pgf/number format/use comma}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis} [view={45}{35},
    xlabel=$\sigma_2$,
    ylabel=$\sigma_1$,
    zlabel={$\phi$},
    %zmin=-6E-5,
    %zmax=0,
    grid=major,
    colormap/blackwhite,
    title={Grafico}]

\addplot3 [surf,z buffer=sort] file {grafico.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Try to compile it as I wrote and look at the surface. Now try to uncomment the lines `zmin =-6E-5` and `zmax = 0,` and recompile. As you can see the clip of the surface is made ​​with respect to the outermost edge of the chart and not with respect to the plane `z = 0,` as it should be.

I also tried with the analytical formulation:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{/pgf/number format/use comma,compat=1.8}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis} [view={25}{35},
    xlabel=$\sigma_1$,
    ylabel=$\sigma_2$,
    zlabel={$\varphi$},
%   xmin=-.0025,
%   xmax=.0025,
%   ymin=-.01,
%   ymax=.01,
    zmin=-6E-5,
    zmax=0,
    grid=major,
    colormap/blackwhite,
    title={Grafico}]

\addplot3 [surf, shader=interp, z buffer=sort, samples=15, domain=-.0025:.0025, y domain=-.01:.01] {y^2-.9^2*(x-2.8E-3)^2+2*4.032E-3*(x-2.8E-3)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

But also this does not work. Do you know how to correct this error? Or, can you tell me where I'm wrong?

Comment: You are right `pgfplots` just clips the 2d image - its 3d features are not fully developed.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. `:)` Note that you don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://$SITEURL$/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @Andrew. I hope that one day even the 3D features will be fully developed.

Comment: Thanks @ClaudioFiandrino! I will follow the directions you gave me.

Answer (score 8):

You could either set the too high/too low values to the upper/lower boundary via `max()`/`min()` constructions (which might be undesirable), or you can use the `z filter` key. As with both the plot becomes more "unsmooth", I used `samples=50`, which makes things a lot slower, so probably you should use the *external* library of *TikZ*.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{/pgf/number format/use comma,compat=1.8}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[   view={25}{35},
  xlabel=$\sigma_1$,
  ylabel=$\sigma_2$,
  zlabel={$\varphi$},
  grid=major,
  %colormap/blackwhite,
  title={Grafico},
  unbounded coords=jump,
]
\addplot3 [surf, shader=interp, z buffer=sort, samples=50, domain=-.0025:.0025, y domain=-.01:.01] {min(max(y^2-.9^2*(x-2.8E-3)^2+2*4.032E-3*(x-2.8E-3),-6E-5),0)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[   view={25}{35},
  xlabel=$\sigma_1$,
  ylabel=$\sigma_2$,
  zlabel={$\varphi$},
  grid=major,
  %colormap/blackwhite,
  title={Grafico},
  z filter/.code={\pgfmathparse{or(#1>0,#1<-0.00006) ? nan : #1}},
  unbounded coords=jump,
  %unbounded coords=discard, % looks worse than jump
]
\addplot3 [surf, shader=interp, z buffer=sort, samples=50, domain=-.0025:.0025, y domain=-.01:.01] {y^2-.9^2*(x-2.8E-3)^2+2*4.032E-3*(x-2.8E-3)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

---

**Edit 1:** As *Jake* pointed out, I reinvented the wheel and did manually what you can do with the keys `restrict z to domain*=-6E-5` and `restrict z to domain=-6E-5`, where the former will yield the left output, while the latter will yield the right.

Comment: @Jake: D'oh! That key sounded oddly familiar, and checking old documents I found that I already used it in the past, but forgot about it. I'll update my post in a few minutes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Your code works (I have not figured out how to use the key `restrict z to domain * =-6E-5` is the key `restrict z to domain =-6E-5`). Unfortunately, however, I find that the graphics quality is still not satisfactory. Fortunately in my document there will be one or two of 3D graphics similar to this. Therefore I believe that I could use the first solution that you suggested, perhaps by drawing a line with the curve of intersection between the surface and the plane is `z = 0.` I hope that this problem will soon be solved by the authors of the excellent package `TikZ.`

Comment: Iy you can describe the points of your funtion as _(x-Expression, y-Expression, z-Expression)_, you can improve the appearance like [seen here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28775/7279)